# jsp login authentication with database user

Tags: database, jsp, authentication

i would like to authenticate user and password which the data store in database. I'm using Netbeans IDE in my decelopment. The problem I faced is it keep show an error page with content internal server error. Can someone one help me to check my code. I have some code like this:

LoginForm.jsp:

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
        <title>Login Form</title> 
    </head> 
    <body bgcolor="#D8CEF6"> 
        <h1>Login Page</h1> 
        <fieldset>
           <center>
      <legend><h2>Sign in Details</h2> </legend>
        <form action="LoginCheck.jsp" method="post"> 

            <br/>Username:<input type="text" name="username"/> 
            <br/>Password:<input type="password" name="password"/> 
            <br/>
            <tr>
            <td>usertype</td>
            <td>
                <select name="usertype">
                    <option value="student">student</option>
                    <option value="faculty">faculty</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
            <br/><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="bt"/> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form> 
    </center> 
                </fieldset>
        </body> 
        </html>
```

LoginCheck.jsp:

```
<%@page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import ="java.io.IOException" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> 
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
    <html> 
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Login Check</title> 
        </head> 
        <body> 
            <%
            String username = request.getParameter("username");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
            String userType = request.getParameter("usertype");
            String dbURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/learningApp";
            String dbuser = "learningApp";
            String dbpassword = "p@ssw0rd";
            Connection theConnection = null;
            PreparedStatement theStatement = theConnection.prepareStatement("select * from USERNAME where username=? and password=?");
            try{
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Class Not Found");
            }
            try{
            theConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbuser, dbpassword);
            }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Connection Error");
            }
            try{
                theStatement.setString(1,request.getParameter("username"));
                theStatement.setString(2,request.getParameter("password"));
                ResultSet theResult = theStatement.executeQuery();
                if(theResult.next()){
            response.sendRedirect("Home.jsp");
        }

            }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Statement Error");
            }


            %>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

My database name is learningApp with password p@ssw0rd
and have a table named USERNAME with a user(username = alice, password = alice)

Comment: From only the code it's very hard to figure out what you are running into.  If you get an error page it's probably due to some exception being thrown. Maybe you can extend the post with your stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to place the `derbyclient.jar`and `derby.jar` in the `WebContent/WEB-INF/Lib` and also include the same in the build path.

Update:

I changed your code (LoginCheck.jsp) to this , (I'm using Oracle DB). Seems to be working fine for me.

```
 <body> 
        <%
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String userType = request.getParameter("usertype");
        String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        String dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.113.130.22:1521:ORCL";
        String dbuser = "user";
        String dbpassword = "password";
        Connection theConnection = null;
        PreparedStatement theStatement = null;


            try{  
                Class.forName(driver);
                theConnection=DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,dbuser,dbpassword);  
                theStatement = theConnection.prepareStatement("select * from USERNAME where username=? and password=?");
                theStatement.setString(1,request.getParameter("username"));
                theStatement.setString(2,request.getParameter("password"));
                ResultSet theResult = theStatement.executeQuery();

                if(theResult.next())
                    System.out.println("Success");
                else
                    System.out.println("Failed");

                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Exception occured! "+e.getMessage()+" "+e.getStackTrace());
                }  
        %>
</body>
```